# Delete function doesn't work in MVC application-Does not delete from DB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make a delete function in my application that the user should be able to delete a product from the table but  when the user presses the delete button, the error message "InvalidOperationException: Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached" comes up. I can't figure out what the problem is because it get's the product the user want's to delete(and displays it in the view) but when it get's to the HttpPost method, (when the user confirms that he want's to delete this product by pressing the delete button), the error message comes up... All the other methods work(create,edit,list...)only the delete method doesn't. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.
this is my code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {

        var p= prodRepo.GetProductById(id);
        return View(p);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(Product product)
    {   

        prodRepo.DeleteProduct(product);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");


    }
```

this is the code from the productRepository class...
     public Product DeleteProduct(Product product)
       {
           db = new NorthwindDataContext();
           db.Products.DeleteOnSubmit(product);
           db.SubmitChanges();
           return product;
       }

```
   public Product GetProductById(int id)
   {
       db = new NorthwindDataContext();
       var prod = (from p in db.Products
                   where p.ProductID==id
                   select p).Single();
       return prod;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the id of product in delete action

```
  [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
     {

         Product_Table Ptobj = db.Product_Table.find(id);
         db.Product_Table.remove(Ptobj);
         db.savechanges()
     }
```